# Simplifying LINQ - Sum of a Col twice with two different where clause

Tags: c#, linq

I have below snippet which takes two round trips to DB, as where clause is different.

```
public string OutStanding(string PC)
{
    var d = _context.MyTable.Where(w => w.debit == PC).Sum(s => s.amount);
    var c = _context.MyTable.Where(w => w.credit == PC).Sum(s => s.amount);
    return (d - c).ToString();
}
```

Can it be simplified to one round trip to DB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
return _context.MyTable.
          Where(w => w.debit == PC || w.credit == PC).
          Sum(s => w.credit == PC ? -s.amount : s.amount).ToString();
```

But check the generated sql. Depending on the version of EF and used database this might be evaluated on the client.

Comment: I think you will need to call `.ToList()` between your `.Where()` and `.Sum()` calls :\

Comment: @vasily.sib Why? The entire sum is retrieved in a single database call.

Comment: @ZevSpitz I'm not sure if LINQ to Entities can handle this `.Sum()` call

Comment: @vasily.sib The problem is not in the `Sum` but in the ternary if in the expression, if anything.

Comment: @ZevSpitz this is exactly what I worry about. If you call `.ToList()` before this `.Sum()` it will handled by LINQ to Objects and this code will be working for sure.

Comment: @vasily.sib But if you call `.ToList` before the `Sum`, EF has to pull from the database all the information needed to construct all the objects in the `List<MyTableEntity>`, whereas without the `.ToList`, EF will only pull a single number from the database. IIRC EF knows what to do with the ternary if.

Comment: @ZevSpitz, sure. If you recall correctly then it will be more preferable way. I just asking someone (OP or anyone else) to test it and share the results.

Comment: @vasily.sib the ternary if seems to works with EF6. It gets transformed in a "CASE WHEN THEN”. But as always with EF and complex queries, it's important to check the generated sql.

Answer (score 3):

You can apply the query and extract later

```
public string OutStanding(string PC) {
    var myTable =_context.MyTable.Where(w => w.debit == PC || w.credit == PC).ToList();
    var d = myTable.Where(w => w.debit == PC).Sum(s => s.amount);
    var c = myTable.Where(w => w.credit == PC).Sum(s => s.amount);
    return (d - c).ToString(); 
}
```

Comment: This is still not as efficient as it might be. It's forcing EF to pull all the data needed to construct all the entities in `MyTable`, when all we actually need is a single number.,

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest getting the final differrence in a single query.

```
public string OutStanding(string PC)
{
    return _context.MyTable.Take(1).Select(x =>
        _context.MyTable.Where(w => w.debit == PC).Sum(s => s.amount) -
        _context.MyTable.Where(w => w.credit == PC).Sum(s => -s.amount)
    );
}
```

the idea being to get an SQL statement like the following:

```
-- replace PC with the equivalent numeric value
SELECT (
    SELECT SUM(Amount) AS subtotal FROM MyTable WHERE debit = PC
) - (
    SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM MyTable WHERE credit = PC
)
```

although it actually will look more like this (on SQL Server):

```
-- replace PC with the equivalent numeric value
SELECT TOP 1 (
    SELECT SUM(Amount) AS subtotal FROM MyTable WHERE debit = PC
) - (
    SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM MyTable WHERE credit = PC
) AS Difference
FROM MyTable
```

Comment: How would you do that?

Comment: the content you posted need to be in comments

Comment: @Bharathi Updated.

Comment: @sriharsha Updated.

Comment: @vasily.sib In fact, `.Concat` is the more appropriate choice here.

Comment: How would you concat an int?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can simplify it to one round trip to DB, something like

```
public string OutStanding(string PC)
{
    var rawData = _context.MyTable.Where(w => w.debit == PC || w.credit == PC).ToList();
                                                          //^^ using OR operator 
    var d = rawData.Where(w => w.debit == PC).Sum(s => s.amount);
    var c = rawData.Where(w => w.credit== PC).Sum(s => s.amount);
    return (d - c).ToString();
}
```

Comment: I want to get both sum in one query instead querying large data and performing two Sum on it.

Comment: This is stil going to be 2 queries to the database, as long as you haven't used `.ToList` in between, or called `AsEnumerable` to force use of `Enumerable.Where` on the query.